# Convert vb.net Linq to c# Group by, with sum & max & min

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to convert a VB.NET Linq Query to C#

I'm not sure how to do the group by and select Sum, Max & Min in one line statement in C#, can this be done in c# and if so a pointer on how.

VB.NET Linq Query

```
Dim rule4Summed = (From r In ArkleSelection1.ArkleMarket1.Rule4sList
                        Where r.Rule4ApplicationCode = "E" And r.DeductionEndTime >Bet.BetSlip.DateScanned
                        Group By r.ArkleMarket1.MarketIdentifier Into
                        sumR4 = Sum(r.DeductionPercentForRunner),
                        dedEndTime = Max(r.DeductionEndTime),
                        dedStartTime = Min(r.DeductionStartTime)).FirstOrDefault
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:-

```
var rule4Summed = (from r in ArkleSelection1.ArkleMarket1.Rule4sList
                  where r.Rule4ApplicationCode == "E" 
                        && r.DuductionEndTime > Bet.Betslip.DateScanned
                  group r by r.ArkleMarket1.MarketIdentifier into g
                  select new 
                  {
                     sumR4 = g.Sum(x => x.DeductionPercentForRunner),
                     dedEndTime = g.Max(x => x.DeductionEndTime),
                     dedStartTime = g.Min(x => x.DeductionStartTime)
                  }).FirstOrDefault();
```